# How to disable passport.js sessions based on request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, session, passport.js

Passport allows sessions with the passport-local library with the following code, but I can't figure a way to toggle `session` based on the request object.

Current code: `router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { session: true }), login)`

Request contains the `persist` boolean in `req.body`

I figured that I can pass the request to my `Strategy` function with the following code:

```
passport.use(
  new Strategy(
    { usernameField: 'email', passReqToCallback: true },
    passportStrategy
  )
)
```

```
export const passportStrategy = async (
  req: Request,
  email: string,
  password: string,
  done: Function
) => {
  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email })
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' })
    }
    const matches = await comparePassword(password, user.password!)
    if (!matches) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' })
    }

    return done(null, user)
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err)
  }
}
```

but that doesn't affect the session code.

The reason I want to disable sessions is in case users are on a public computer, so perhaps there's a way of deleting the session either immediately client side or in my route handler?